# Didn't recive mortarboard badge

Tags: support, badges

The info about the [Mortarboard](https://superuser.com/help/badges/43/mortarboard) badge says that anyone who has earned 200 reputation (or more) in a single day should get this badge.
Yesterday I earned 267 reputation,
[image]
But I didn't get the badge.

How do I resolve this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: [The reference guide to badges on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've received 100 rep as an Association bonus. The badge doesn't take into consideration rep received from Association bonus for the badge

Comment: It's a shame :(

Comment: Unless you were kidding, no it's not. 100 rep is significantly easier to achieve than double that amount, and clubbing the association bonus along with it is not fair by any means. The bonus is obviously a sort of reward in itself.

Comment: /cc @matan129 .

Comment: I **was** kidding. Relax people!